# How to get content from a div using regex

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have string like :

```
<div class="fck_detail">
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="tplCaption" width="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>
            <img alt="nole-1375196668_500x0.jpg" src="http://l.f1.img.vnexpress.net/2013/07/30/nole-1375196668_500x0.jpg" width="500">                
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td class="Image">
                Djokovic hậm hực với các đàn anh. Ảnh: <em>Livetennisguide.</em>
            </td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>Riêng với Andy Murray, ...</p>
    <p style="text-align:right;"><strong>Anh Hào</strong></p> 
</div>
```

I want to get content . How to write this pattern using preg_match. Please help me

Comment: Why would you use preg_match to put content into a div?  preg_match would be better suited for getting content out of the div.

Comment: sorry my bad English . I want get content out div

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no other HTML tags inside the div, then this regex should work:

```
$v = '<div class="fck_detail">Some content here</div>';
$regex = '#<div class="fck_detail">([^<]*)</div>#';
preg_match($regex, $v, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

The actual regex here is `<div class="fck_detail">([^<]*)</div>`.  Regexes used in PHP also need to be surrounded by some other character that doesn't occur in the regex (I used `#`).

However, if what you're parsing is arbitrary HTML provided by the user, then `preg_match` simply can't do this.  Full-fledged HTML parsing is beyond the ability of any regex, and that's what you'll need if you're parsing the output of a full-fledged HTML editor.

Comment: If the original div contains any other `<html>` tags this will fail.

Comment: Complete HTML parsing is impossible using a regex, but if you know what format to expect the page in, you can use a regex to pick out the part you need.

Comment: fck is a GUI html editor. If this is called fck_detail because it's the Div they're using for editing, at the point someone selects type and makes it italic it will break the code.

Comment: i can't get all content because my full string contain table and Paragraph(<p>)

Comment: Can your string contain another `div` ever?  If not, then changing the regex to `<div class="fck_detail">([\s\S]*?)</div>` will work.  However, make doubly sure that the div will never contain another div if you do that, because if it does, you will get the wrong answer with no errors.

Comment: Will your string always start with `<div class="fck_detail">` and end with `</div>`?  If so, then remove the question mark from that last regex I mentioned, and it will work even if there are other divs inside.